# What's the difference between input/output streams and ordinary reader and writer and what's the difference between their types?

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, writer, reader

Now I don't seem to get the difference between those streams (Input/Output) and the ordinary `writer` and `reader` or even the `scanner` and `formatter` ...

and why does the `InputStream` have a lot of sub classes like `DataInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream`and all that mess (and the same for `OutputStream` of course) ...

one last thing, if the buffer is that good (So I read) and efficient why would any one use any other input/output way (Why was they even made?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Streams [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)/[write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) **bytes**, while [Readers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) read and [Writers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) write **character** data. Since underneath it all you always have bytes when doing I/O, this means that readers and writers do an additional step of [converting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) bytes to characters.

There are abstract super-classes for both cases (the ones I just linked), with various subclasses, not just for streams -- you can see for yourself in the Javadoc, each page lists sub-classes for all of these.

Buffers make sense if you want to collect a chunk of data first before processing. One good reason is, for instance, that disk access is more efficient if you read/write a chunk of data at once, rather than reading/writing each byte/character individually. But of course, there are lots of different situations in which you may want to do I/O -- not one size fits all, and so there are different classes tailored to these different situations.

The reason buffered versions were made at all is the basic principle of object oriented programming: by decoupling functionality you get less complex mechanisms/designs while at the same time addressing a wider range of possible applications, as described above.

Comment: can you show an example of converting **bytes** to **characters** and vice versa ?

Comment: Check out `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` -- their constructors take a stream object (source/sink for the bytes) and a `Charset` that has the information how to map between bytes and characters. You use them like you use any other reader/writer, i.e., via the normal `read` and `write` methods. But if you just want to read/write existing character data (say, read a text file from disk), you don't have to do this conversion manually: the various Reader/Writer classes do that internally for you.

Comment: and which `Charset` should be used and depending on what ?

Comment: That depends on the task: if you're *writing* character data ("encoding"), you should make sure that the `Charset` contains a mapping to bytes for all (special) characters contained in the data. If you're *reading* data ("decoding"), you should use the same `Charset` that was used to encode the data when it was written. Standard character sets in use today include `UTF-8`, `ISO-8859-1`, and `US-ASCII` -- check out the Javadoc for `Charset` for more information.